# Qiskit Encoding of a Hamiltonian

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-operation

I am not sure if this is a trivial question and I am just stuck or this is worth posting.
I have a Hamiltonian, which is written in terms of Pauli matrices, such as

H = 4.5$I$ - 16 $X_1$ - 16 $X_2$ - 3.5 $Z_1Z_4$ -3.5 $Z_1Z_2Z_3$

and I would like to write it as a CH gate in qiskit to find the energy of the ground state. The idea is to write the Hamiltonian into matrix form and write
$\matrix{\mathbb{1}\ 0\\
0\ H}$ as a matrix.

Then use the QuantumCircuit.unitary() command to encode it.
My issue is that H is non-unitary, this can be seen by already my first term 4.5$I$, where $I$ is $\mathbb{1}$. Is there a simple trick of encoding my Hamiltonian in a quantum circuit on qiskit?

Comment: A very similar question was posted shortly after this question with a better answer: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23635/how-to-construct-a-hamiltonian-containing-pauli-string-by-qiskit I vote to mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the Operator Flow feature be helpful?

https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/operators/01_operator_flow.html

Comment: this works perfectly, it forces me to write each gate individually as CX gate but it is possible. Thank you